# Use of the MANIFEST.MF file in Java

Tags: java, jar, manifest.mf, meta-inf

I noticed that JAR, WAR and EAR files have a `MANIFEST.MF` file under the `META-INF` folder.

What is the use of the `MANIFEST.MF` file? What all things can be specified in this file?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifest_file

Comment: See [Working with Manifest Files: The Basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html).

Answer (score 106, accepted):

The content of the Manifest file in a JAR file created with version 1.0 of the Java Development Kit is the following.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
```

All the entries are as name-value pairs. The name of a header is separated from its value by a colon. The default manifest shows that it conforms to version 1.0 of the manifest specification.
The manifest can also contain information about the other files that are packaged in the archive. Exactly what file information is recorded in the manifest will depend on the intended use for the JAR file. The default manifest file makes no assumptions about what information it should record about other files, so its single line contains data only about itself.
Special-Purpose Manifest Headers

Depending on the intended role of the JAR file, the default manifest may have to be modified. If the JAR file is created only for the purpose of archival, then the MANIFEST.MF file is of no purpose.
Most uses of JAR files go beyond simple archiving and compression and require special information to be in the manifest file. Summarized below are brief descriptions of the headers that are required for some special-purpose JAR-file functions

**Applications Bundled as JAR Files:** If an application is bundled in a JAR file, the Java Virtual Machine needs to be told what the entry point to the application is. An entry point is any class with a public static void main(String[] args) method. This information is provided in the Main-Class header, which has the general form:

```
Main-Class: classname
```

The value classname is to be replaced with the application's entry point.

**Download Extensions:** Download extensions are JAR files that are referenced by the manifest files of other JAR files. In a typical situation, an applet will be bundled in a JAR file whose manifest references a JAR file (or several JAR files) that will serve as an extension for the purposes of that applet. Extensions may reference each other in the same way.
Download extensions are specified in the Class-Path header field in the manifest file of an applet, application, or another extension. A Class-Path header might look like this, for example:

```
Class-Path: servlet.jar infobus.jar acme/beans.jar
```

With this header, the classes in the files servlet.jar, infobus.jar, and acme/beans.jar will serve as extensions for purposes of the applet or application. The URLs in the Class-Path header are given relative to the URL of the JAR file of the applet or application.

**Package Sealing:** A package within a JAR file can be optionally sealed, which means that all classes defined in that package must be archived in the same JAR file. A package might be sealed to ensure version consistency among the classes in your software or as a security measure.
To seal a package, a Name header needs to be added for the package, followed by a Sealed header, similar to this:

```
Name: myCompany/myPackage/
Sealed: true
```

The Name header's value is the package's relative pathname. Note that it ends with a '/' to distinguish it from a filename. Any headers following a Name header, without any intervening blank lines, apply to the file or package specified in the Name header. In the above example, because the Sealed header occurs after the Name: myCompany/myPackage header, with no blank lines between, the Sealed header will be interpreted as applying (only) to the package myCompany/myPackage.

**Package Versioning:** The Package Versioning specification defines several manifest headers to hold versioning information. One set of such headers can be assigned to each package. The versioning headers should appear directly beneath the Name header for the package. This example shows all the versioning headers:

```
Name: java/util/
Specification-Title: "Java Utility Classes" 
Specification-Version: "1.2"
Specification-Vendor: "Sun Microsystems, Inc.".
Implementation-Title: "java.util" 
Implementation-Version: "build57"
Implementation-Vendor: "Sun Microsystems, Inc."
```

Additional information: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html

Comment: Please do not copy someone work. You should add a link to the web page. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/sealman.html

Comment: It's not a copy, more a summary...of 5 pages.

Comment: You can call this summary. The sentences ware copied, without any additional conclusion or point. I think that you should respect someone work and add links and quotes.

Answer (score 27):

Manifest.MF contains information about the files contained in the JAR file.

Whenever a JAR file is created a default manifest.mf file is created inside META-INF folder and it contains the default entries like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.7.0_06 (Oracle Corporation)
```

These are entries as “header:value” pairs. The first one specifies the manifest version and second one specifies the JDK version with which the JAR file is created.

**Main-Class header:**
When a JAR file is used to bundle an application in a package, we need to specify the class serving an entry point of the application. We provide this information using ‘Main-Class’ header of the manifest file,

Main-Class: {fully qualified classname}

The ‘Main-Class’ value here is the class having main method. After specifying this entry we can execute the JAR file to run the application.

**Class-Path header:**
Most of the times we need to access the other JAR files from the classes packaged inside application’s JAR file. This can be done by providing their fully qualified paths in the manifest file using ‘Class-Path’ header,

Class-Path: {jar1-name jar2-name directory-name/jar3-name}

This header can be used to specify the external JAR files on the same local network and not inside the current JAR.

**Package version related headers:**
When the JAR file is used for package versioning the following headers are used as specified by the Java language specification:

```
Headers in a manifest
Header                  | Definition
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Name                    | The name of the specification.
Specification-Title     | The title of the specification.
Specification-Version   | The version of the specification.
Specification-Vendor    | The vendor of the specification.
Implementation-Title    | The title of the implementation.
Implementation-Version  | The build number of the implementation.
Implementation-Vendor   | The vendor of the implementation.
```

**Package sealing related headers:**

We can also specify if any particular packages inside a JAR file should be sealed meaning all the classes defined in that package must be archived in the same JAR file. This can be specified with the help of ‘Sealed’ header,

Name: {package/some-package/}
Sealed:true

Here, the package name must end with ‘/’.

**Enhancing security with manifest files:**

We can use manifest files entries to ensure the security of the web application or applet it packages with the different attributes as ‘Permissions’, ‘Codebae’, ‘Application-Name’, ‘Trusted-Only’ and many more.

**META-INF folder:**

This folder is where the manifest file resides. Also, it can contain more files containing meta data about the application. For example, in an EJB module JAR file, this folder contains the EJB deployment descriptor for the EJB module along with the manifest file for the JAR. Also, it contains the xml file containing mapping of an abstract EJB references to concrete container resources of the application server on which it will be run.

Reference:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html