# jar Error using customized MANIFEST.MF file

Tags: java, jar

Continuing from my previous [UseOfManifestFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20066184/confusion-on-uses-of-jar-manifest-file) thread, i advanced to use my own MANIFEST.MF
file rather then using the default one created from the jar tool. I am attaching the snapshot here.
[image: Sample Directory Structure And Command]. It shows my directory structure as well as the command i am using. It's not using my MANIFEST.MF file. I don't know why and default is getting created. What mistake i am committing? I also swapped the MANIFEST.MF file name and jar name and now it gives the following error.

[image: Swapped Command]

Can anyone help me in this.

**Directory Structure**

d:->corejava
            |
             chapter10
                      |
                       tictactoe.jar
                                    |
                                     tictactoe
                                              |
                                              HelloWorld.class , audio(folder), images(folder)

My point is, i was able to add the contents of Manifest.txt into the MANIFEST.MF file. Now when
i try to run the jar from chapter directory using the following command :-

```
java jar tictactoe.jar
```

It gives the following error to me

```
Error: Could not find or load main class jar
```

Can someone help me in this.

Comment: As I understand your question is why is there a default MANIFEST entries along with your custom MANIFEST? Correct me if I am wrong.

If my understanding is correct, jar cfm creates a jar file by merging the text file you pass with the default MANIFEST file f indicates the output to go to a file than standard output.

See the below link which gives you in detail about the jar command and usage.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/modman.html

Comment: No Abhijith, actually i wanted to mark the entry for Main class in my jar. So i saw how i can add additional instructions to the mainfest file. i gave command as jar cfm jarname Manifest.txt tictactoue. Issue is, its not merging my addition with main Manifest file.

Comment: Can you add the contents of Manifest.txt?

Comment: “shows my directory structure” **what** shows your directory structure? I don’t see any directory structure nor any other indication that it didn’t work.

Comment: i have tried to add the directory structure and now it gives the error when i try to run the jar, it can't find or load main class.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue. Here are the points which i concluded and successfully executed the program.

1. Make sure your Manifest.txt file ends with a carriage return as per the instructions [Setting An Application Entry Point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html). Otherwise it won't be parsed correctly.
2. If it's in a package make sure, its properly compiled.
3. The command to run a jar is given below

   java -jar JarName.jar

I followed the above steps and was able to execute my program.

Thanks everyone.