# Use of MANIFEST.MF file under META-INF folder

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, browser-cache, sapui5, web-development-server

Can some one tell me the use of `MANIFEST.MF` file in web application projects?

Is it related to restricting cache?

I am exploring this in order to make my application ignore cache when it is loaded for the first time in browser. Please assist.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of manifest file in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12767886/use-of-manifest-file-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the Application Cache Buster mechanism, the first request must never be cached because it is being used to fetch the index file. The following list explains the flow

```
http://myserver/myapp/sap-ui-cachebuster-info.json ⇒ NO_CACHE
http://myserver/myapp/~201106210204~/mvc/MyMVC.view.js ⇒ CACHE
http://myserver/myapp/mvc/MyMVC.view.js ⇒ internally resolve to this URL
```

you can find more information in  [Developer Guide](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/d415dd8911a645759373dc1a70b93f3d.html)