# What is Manifest-Version in MANIFEST.MF?

Tags: java, jar, manifest, manifest.mf

In the `MANIFEST.MF` file found in JARs, the first line is `Manifest-Version: 1.0`. According to the [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/defman.html), this first line says that "the default manifest conforms to version 1.0 of the manifest specification".

So in what cases would the `Manifest-Version` be anything other than `1.0`?

Also, what is the manifest specification? Why must the default manifest conform to it? I've [seen](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/defman.html) [multiple](http://www.javaexperience.com/purpose-of-meta-inf-folder-and-manifest-mf-file-in-jar-file/) [explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12767886/use-of-manifest-file-in-java) explaining again that "the default manifest conforms to version 1.0 of the manifest specification" but none explaining what the manifest specification is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [JAR File Specification - Manifest Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Manifest_Specification) states,

> Manifest-Version: Defines the manifest file version. The value is a legitimate version number, as described in the above spec.

And version number is

> version-number :               digit+{.digit+}*

There is also a note

> Versions:
>
> Manifest-Version and Signature-Version must be first, and in exactly that case (so that they can be recognized easily as magic strings). Other than that, the order of attributes within a main section is not significant.

I don't believe Sun or Oracle has ever released another version of the Manifest Specification (but they could, and this allows them to provide *future* proofing). Also, it's treated as a magic string.

Comment: So is Manifest-Version the version of the actual manifest file in the JAR, or is it the version of the manifest specification in the JAR File Specification?

Comment: @Rees the second one.