# Trying to run jar file but getting cannot find class

Tags: java, jar

I am trying to run a jar file from the Win7 command line, but am getting the dreaded could not find or load main class PRCreateExecution.

I can successfully build the jar file from a Win7 batch file on the command line.

My current manifest file is named PRCreateExecution.mf and is located in here: C:\WDEclipseIDEWorkspace\MC3\src\PurchaseRequests\

The manifest file contains:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.8.0_40 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: PurchaseRequests.PRCreateExecution.class
```

(extra LF is here)

I run the Win7 batch file to build the jar from
C:\WDEclipseIDEWorkspace\MC3\src\PurchaseRequests:

```
jar -cvmf PRCreateExecution.jar C:\WDEclipseIDEWorkspace\MC3\bin\PurchaseRequests\PRCreateExecution.mf C:\WDEclipseIDEWorkspace\MC3\bin\PurchaseRequests\PRCreateExecution.class C:\WDJarFiles
```

The jar file gets created successfully.

Now I'm using this batch statement to try and run the jar file:

```
java -cp C:\WDEclipseIDEWorkspace\MC3\bin\PurchaseRequests;. PurchaseRequests.PRCreateExecution
```

from in here:

```
C:\WDEclipseIDEWorkspace\MC3\src\PurchaseRequests
```

but am getting the could not find main class PurchaseRequests.PRCreateExecution.

PRCreateExecution source snippet:

```
package PurchaseRequests;
public class PRCreateExecution {
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Thanks for any help...

Comment: Usually when I run `.jar` files from batch files, I use the code `java -jar JarFileName.jar`.

Comment: I'm using a package so I'm pretty sure mine needs to be package.jarFilename.jar

Comment: If you go to `File > Export`, you can select the `class` with the `main` method. Then, export it as a `.jar` file. That way, all referenced code will be put into the `.jar` file. Run it with `java -jar ClassWithMainMethodName.jar`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it sounds like you're not actually trying to run your jar file at all. You're not mentioning it anywhere on your command line.

Secondly, it looks like your classpath is wrong - it should probably be

```
java -cp C:\WDEclipseIDEWorkspace\MC3\bin;. PurchaseRequests.PRCreateExecution
```

That's assuming that the `bin` directory contains a `PurchaseRequests` directory which contains `PRCreateExecution.class`

Thirdly, you should follow Java naming conventions for packages - they should be lower case.

Comment: When I run your suggested line: java -cp C:\WDEclipseIDEWorkspace\MC3\bin;. PurchaseRequests.PRCreateExecution I get an Error:A JNI error has occurred.

Comment: @user337447: Well that sounds like a different problem, and we don't have enough context to help you further.

Comment: @mp911de gave me the solution but I don't see where to click to give him the credit.

Comment: @user337447: You can click on the tick.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar kind of issue building distributable jar files using Netbeans. My suggestion would be to try and run the jar directly from the command line and from within the directory path of its location.

It is seen that you have something like this in your manifest file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0 Created-By: 1.8.0_40 (Oracle Corporation) Main-Class: PurchaseRequests.PRCreateExecution.class (extra LF is here)
```

I suggest you change the lines as follows:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0 Created-By: 1.8.0_40 (Oracle Corporation) (insert CF)
Main-Class: PurchaseRequests.PRCreateExecution.class (extra LF is here)
```

You may use this as your reference:

```
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html
```

This post might be of use, too:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12767886/use-of-manifest-file-in-java
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the .class suffix from the manifest.

It should look like:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.8.0_40 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: PurchaseRequests.PRCreateExecution
```

Afterwards run `java -jar (name of your jar-file).jar`

Comment: I removed the .class from the .mf file.
java -jar PurchaseRequests.PRCreateExecution.jar
Error:Unable to access jarfile PurchaseRequests.PRCreateExecution.jar

Comment: I had a typo but your response was the solution. How do I give you the credit?