# When does manifest file created in java?

Tags: java, command-prompt

I have a basic question about the manifest file: when is this file created?

Is it created in the .class file when we compile a java file? Or should we create the manifest file from the command line after the .class file is created?

Update: you can find the answer here:  [Use of the MANIFEST.MF file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12767886/use-of-the-manifest-mf-file-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manifest file has nothing to do with the compilation/running process of a class.

If you configured your project correctly in your IDE (depending on the IDE), it will be generated during the build project process.

If you are working using the command prompt and notepad, you can always create it manually.