# Parse java manifest file in C#

Tags: c#

Is there any solution to parse a java manifest (manifest.mf) file in C#?

I need to get values from it.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you even tried *anything*? Parsing a simple text-file is quite standard-stuff and you should be able to google it and find dozens of examples (not neccessarily for manifest-files but you´ll get the idea).

Comment: I just googled out of curiosity. Looks so trivial compared to xml. Should be easy

Comment: As I see, it's not follows any convention, of course I can do it, with string-manipulation, but I believed there is a standard solution to parse it, like xml or json... In Java, as I saw, there is a class for parsing this file. I tried to analyze the structure of it, but for me, it's really unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that there's a C# Specific library for this, but this question ([Use of the MANIFEST.MF file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12767886/use-of-the-manifest-mf-filein-java)) has a great overview of the file, what it's for, and a lot of other helpful information.

That being said, the quick and dirty way (in my opinion) for how to do this would be split every line by a colon, the first value in the array is the header name, and *all other values* after that, would be the value. (just in case your value has a colon in it, I'm unsure if that's allowed by the spec or not but, but I'd assume so.